# how to upload to folder and replace files using python and Google Drive?

Tags: python, file-upload, google-drive-api, google-api-python-client

I crafted this little script which helps me upload files from terminal to Google Drive. I am going to use it with cron to make my life easier a bit. 
This is the script I have: https://github.com/goranpejovic/drive-uploader/blob/master/upload.py

It essentially uploads file to GDrive and optionally converts it to Google Docs format. Now, I want to implement two more things but I am not sure how.

First is I want to have ability to upload to folders remotely. Not just create folder locally and upload it (this would be nice too now when I think of it), but upload file to remote folder in Google Drive. Is this possible? If so, any suggestion?

Second, I would like to be able to replace files that already exist on Drive. Obviously same filename doesn't matter to GDrive so I am assuming it has to do with metadata I am passing as "body". Or some other ways?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

To create folders in drive is similar than creating a file, the difference would be the mime type: "application/vnd.google-apps.folder". So instead of uploading a folder, you have to use file.insert to create a new one in Drive.

Creating or inserting a file in Drive, as you mentioned, it will create a new file, even if the name already exists. In order to replace a file, you will have to [update](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/update) the existing file with the new information.